# What are the challenges related to typing in writing a compiler for a dynamically typed language?

Tags: python, compiler

In [this talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EBRMq2Ioxsc), Guido van Rossum is talking (27:30) about attempts to write a compiler for Python code, commenting on it saying:

> turns out it's not so easy to write a compiler that maintains all the
>   nice dynamic typing properties and also maintains semantic correctness
>   of your program, so that it actually does the same thing no matter
>   what kind of weirdness you do somewhere under the covers and actually
>   runs any faster

**What are the (possible) challenges related to typing in writing a compiler for a dynamically typed language like Python?**

Comment: In this case dynamic typing is not nearly the biggest issue. For python it's a dynamic scoping.

Comment: It's worth noting that other people have argued that building dynamic typing into the platform is the right answer here. Microsoft put a lot of money into [DLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Language_Runtime) for exactly this reason—and NeXT/Apple has been half-way on that bandwagon for decades. That doesn't help CPython, but IronPython proves that you can effectively statically compile Python, and PyPy proves that you don't have to.

Comment: The compiler is the easy part, and it's made easier by not having static typing. The runtime system is the hard part.

Comment: @SK-logic Dynamic scoping in Python? Last I checked, all constructs in the language use lexical scoping.

Comment: @delnan, you can define identifiers in Python dynamically (and this feature is widely abused).

Comment: @SK-logic You can dynamically create code and execute it, but that code also runs lexically scoped. For every single variable in a Python program, you can easily determine which scope a variable belongs to just by inspecting the AST. You may be thinking of the [`exec` statement](http://codepad.org/oVWONt74), which is gone since 3.0 and hence outside my consideration (and probably Guido's, as the talk is from 2012). Could you give an example? And your definition of "dynamic scoping", if it's [different from mine](en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_scoping).

Comment: @delnan, I'm talking about things like `globals()` and `locals()`

Comment: @SK-logic, what leads you to believe that `globals()` and `locals()` are widely abused?

Comment: @SK-logic One can't even change the values of existing variables with `locals()`, let alone introduce new ones. Well, apparently `locals()['foo'] = ...; locals()['foo']` does work in CPython, but this is not documented anywhere (read: is an implementation detail), and doesn't affect the meaning of the identifier `foo` anywhere -- if it's global according to static analysis, meddling with `locals` doesn't change that. `globals` is more powerful, but it just allows you to add/remove attributes of the module, which is no different from adding/removing attributes to any other object.

Comment: @delnan, looks like I'm unlucky - I've seen a lot of code abusing `locals()`. But if you dismiss it as implementation detail (alongside with `eval()`), compiling Python statically may become a much easier thing.

Comment: @SK-logic The only thing that's an implementation detail for me is changes to return value of `locals()` persisting across calls to `locals`. What's documented and definitely not an implementation detail is that not even `locals` or `globals` can change in which scope each variable is looked up in. For every single use of a variable, the scope to which is refers is statically determined. Which makes it decidedly lexically scoped. (And btw, `eval` and `exec` are definitely not implementation details either - look at my answer!)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You oversimplified Guido's statement in phrasing your question. The problem isn't writing a compiler for a dynamically-typed language. The problem is writing one that is (criteria 1) always correct, (criteria 2) keeps dynamic typing, *and* (criteria 3) is noticeably faster for a significant amount of code.

It's easy to implement 90% (failing criteria 1) of Python and be consistently fast at it. Similarly, it's easy to create a faster Python variant with static typing (failing criteria 2). Implementing 100% is also easy (insofar implementing a language that complex is easy), but so far every easy way to implement it turns out to be relatively slow (failing criteria 3).

Implementing an interpreter *plus JIT* that's correct, implements the entire language, and is faster for some code turns out to be feasible, though significantly harder (cf. PyPy) and only so if you automate the creation of the JIT compiler (Psyco did without it, but was very limited in what code it could speed up). But note that this is explicitly out of scope, as we're talking about *static* (aka ahead-of-time) compilers. I only mention this to explain why its approach does not work for static compilers (or at least there's no existing counterexample): It first has to interpret and observe the program, then generate code for a specific iteration of a loop (or another linear code path), then optimize the hell out of that based on assumptions only true for that specific iteration (or at least, not for all possible iterations). The expectation is that many later executions of that code will also match the expectation and thus benefit from the optimizations. Some (relatively cheap) checks are added to assure correctness. To do all this, you need an idea of what to specialize for, and a slow but general implementation to fall back to. AOT compilers have neither. They can't specialize *at all* based on code they can't see (e.g. dynamically loaded code), and specializing carelessly means generating more code, which has a number of problems (icache utilization, binary size, compile time, additional branches).

Implementing an AOT compiler that *correctly* implements the *entire* language is also relatively easy: Generate code that calls into the runtime to do what the interpreter would do when fed with this code. [Nuitka](http://nuitka.net/) (mostly) does this. However, this doesn't yield much performance benefit (failing criteria 3), as you still have to do just as much unnecessary work as an interpreter, save for dispatching the bytecode to the block of C code which does what you compiled in. But that's only a rather small cost -- significant enough to be worth optimizing in an existing interpreter, but not significant enough to justify a whole new implementation with its own problems.

What would be needed to fulfill all three criteria? We have no idea. There are some static analysis schemes which can extract some information about concrete types, control flow, etc. from Python programs. The ones that yield accurate data beyond the scope of a single basic block are extremely slow and need to see the whole program, or at least most of it. Still, you can't do much with that information, other than perhaps optimize a few operations on builtin types.

Why's that? To put it bluntly, a compiler either removes the ability to execute Python code loaded at runtime (failing criteria 1), or it does not make any assumptions that can be invalidated by any Python code at all. Unfortunately, that includes pretty much everything useful for optimizing programs: Globals including functions can be rebound, classes can be mutated or replaced entirely, modules can be modified arbitrarily too, importing can be hijacked in several ways, etc. A single string passed to `eval`, `exec`, `__import__`, or numerous other functions, may do any of that. In effect, that means almost no big optimizations can be applied, yielding little performance benefit (failing criteria 3). Back to the above paragraph.

Answer (score 4):

The hardest problem is to figure out what type everything has at any given time.

In a static language like C or Java, once you have seen the type declaration, you know what that object is and what it can do.  If a variable is declared `int`, it is an integer.  It is not, for example, a callable function reference.

In Python, it can be.  This is horrible Python, but legal:

```
i = 2
x = 3 + i

def prn(s):
    print(s)

i = prn
i(x)
```

Now, this example is pretty stupid, but it illustrates the general idea.

More realistically, you might replace a built-in function with a user-defined function that does something slightly different (like a version that logs its arguments when you call it).

PyPy uses Just-In-Time compilation after watching what the code actually does, and this lets PyPy speed things up a lot.  PyPy can watch a loop, and verify that every time the loop runs, variable `foo` is always an integer; then PyPy can optimize away the code that looks up the type of `foo` on every pass through the loop, and can often even get rid of the Python object that represents an integer, and `foo` can just become a number sitting in a register on the CPU.  This is how PyPy can be faster than CPython; CPython does the type lookup as fast as possible, but not even doing the lookup is even faster.

I don't know the details, but I remember there was a project called Unladen Swallow that was trying to apply static compiler technology to speed up Python (using LLVM).  You might want to Google search for Unladen Swallow and see if you can find a discussion of why it didn't work out as they had hoped.

Comment: Unladen Swallow wasn't about static compilation or static types; the eventual going was effectively to port the CPython interpreter, with all its dynamic-ness, to LLVM, with a fancy new JIT (kind of like Parrot, or DLR for .NET… or PyPy, really), although what they actually ended up doing was find a lot of local optimizations within CPython (some of which made it into mainline 3.x). Shedskin is probably the project you're thinking of that used static type inference to statically compile Python (although to C++, not directly to native code).

Comment: One of the Unladen Swallow authors, Reid Kleckner, posted an [Unladen Swallow Retrospective](http://qinsb.blogspot.com/2011/03/unladen-swallow-retrospective.html), which may be worth reading in this context, although really it's more about management and sponsorship challenges than technical ones.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer says, the key problem is figuring out type information.  To the extent you can do that statically, you can directly generate good code.

But even if you can't do it statically, you can still generate reasonable code, just at runtime, when you get *actual* type information.   This information turns out often to be stable, or have at most a few different values for any particular entity at a particular code point.   The [SELF programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self_%28programming_language%29) pioneered many of the ideas of aggressive runtime type collection and runtime code generation.  Its ideas are widely used in modern JIT-based compilers like Java and C#.